ZLIB: How Should I Inflate Deflated Data of Unknown Length
I am inflating some legacy files with zlib.  Unfortunately, the files are comprised of 3 parts:
Part 1: Uncompressed Data followed by
Part 2: zlib deflated data, which begins with 0x789C followed by
Part 3: Uncompressed Data
The files are such that the length of the deflated data is unknown (the adler32 checksum has been removed from Part 2).
What is the correct way to inflate Part 2 of these files?
I'm currently inflating this data using code based on the inf function in the zpipe.c sample program (https://www.zlib.net/zpipe.c).  Inflation proceeds successfully until the last part of the deflated data is processed, at which point I encounter Z_DATA_ERROR(-3), invalid stored block lengths.
If I stop inflation once Z_DATA_ERROR occurs, would this omit a portion of Part 2 of the file, leaving some compressed data unprocessed?
On the other hand, if I process the buffer inflate returns in spite of the Z_DATA_ERROR - hoping to process that last buffer and then stop - the output I receive is filled with extraneous data.
Two examples of such streams are at: https://github.com/hankinsohl/Sample
I've searched the web and cannot find guidance on how to proceed.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Do you have a copy of any "legacy" software that was originally supposed to handle these files? It feels like there's some missing piece of information, which I hope could be reverse engineered from such software.

No, unfortunately I don't have source code for the program which created the data.

I wasn't talking about the source - do you have a binary? Also, if the program is only creating the files, then it may actually be that it just produces garbage that is not deterministically reversible. Ideally you'd have something that was supposed to consume the file, to see how that was doing it...

I do have a copy of the program which creates the files.  The program is able to read/write files in this format successfully.

You will have to experiment to see what happens. One trick you might be able to use is looking at the histogram distribution of bytes to spot where the files transition from compressed to uncompressed data. Compressed data has a much higher byte entropy using almost all symbols equally. The other is take  a look in the debugger at the region where the decoder faults it and hope that there is some recognisable start of uncompressed data block header there (or content in ASCII text).  If you can make toy files using the old software to try and decode so much the better.

An idea I'm contemplating, is to perform trial inflations of Part 2, increasing and then decreasing a trial data length until a final length is found which results in error-free inflation, but beyond which, inflation errors occur.  I was hoping that a better solution exists.

The only reliable way to figure out what's going on would be static reverse engineering.

A correct and complete zlib stream is self-terminating. It tells you where it ends by ending. You will get Z_STREAM_END back from inflate(), and whatever is left unused in inflate's input buffer is what follows the zlib stream.
However if you are getting a Z_DATA_ERROR, then it is not a correct zlib stream. It has been corrupted somewhere along the way.
Update given example data:
For the two examples provided, the "zlib" streams end with an empty, non-last stored block. These are, of course, not valid zlib streams, hence the quotes. They start with a zlib header, but the deflate compressed data does not have a block marked as the last block.
To reliably find the end, you would need to inflate using Z_BLOCK, which returns at the end of a deflate block, signaling such an end using the data_type member of the structure (see the documentation in zlib.h). The latter is to distinguish returns that are due simply to consuming all of the input data or using all of the output space.
Once getting to the end of block, look ahead to see if the next three bits are zeros, and if the next four bytes (after discarding bits as needed to get to a byte boundary) are 00 00 ff ff.
Alternatively you could simply look for an empty deflate block, also using Z_BLOCK. This assumes that the only empty deflate block that appears is the terminating empty stored block. Here is an example of code that does that:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "zlib.h"

// Raw inflate from in to out until the end of the deflate stream or until an
// empty deflate block is read. The return value is Z_OK if ended on an empty
// deflate block, Z_STREAM_END if the deflate stream terminated, Z_DATA_ERROR
// if the compressed data is invalid, or Z_BUF_ERROR if the input ends before
// an end condition is encountered. inbuf is an input buffer with length *len
// provided by the application. Upon return inbuf[0..*len-1] are unused input
// bytes that followed the end of the consumed deflate data. An error reading
// or writing will return Z_ERRNO.
int inf2empty(FILE *in, FILE *out, unsigned char *inbuf, unsigned *len) {
    z_stream strm = {0};
    int ret = inflateInit2(&strm, -15);
    if (ret != Z_OK)
        return ret;
    unsigned char outbuf[32768];
    unsigned long long block = 0;
    do {
        if (strm.avail_in == 0) {
            strm.avail_in = fread(inbuf, 1, *len, in);
            strm.next_in = inbuf;
            if (strm.avail_in < *len && ferror(in)) {
                ret = Z_ERRNO;
                break;
            }
        }
        strm.avail_out = sizeof(out);
        strm.next_out = outbuf;
        ret = inflate(&strm, Z_BLOCK);
        unsigned put = sizeof(out) - strm.avail_out;
        if (fwrite(outbuf, 1, put, out) != put) {
            ret = Z_ERRNO;
            break;
        }
        block += put;
        if (strm.data_type & 128) {
            // At the end of a deflate block. We're done if it was empty.
            if (block == 0)
                break;
            block = 0;
        }
    } while (ret == Z_OK);
    inflateEnd(&strm);
    memmove(inbuf, strm.next_in, strm.avail_in);
    *len = strm.avail_in;
    return ret;
}

// Read input from stdin until a 78 9c zlib header is encountered. Then do a
// raw inflate from there, writing the uncompressed output to stdout. Stop when
// an empty deflate block or a last deflate block is encountered. Then show the
// first 16 bytes (or less) that follow the decoded deflate data in hex on
// stderr.
int main(void) {
    // Look for the start of the "zlib" stream.
    int ch, word = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        word = (word << 8) + ch;
        if ((word & 0xffff) == 0x789c)
            break;
    }

    // Decompress from after the zlib header to the first empty deflate block.
    unsigned char inbuf[32768];
    unsigned len = sizeof(inbuf);
    int ret = inf2empty(stdin, stdout, inbuf, &len);
    if (ret != Z_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "** unexpected %s\n", zError(ret));
        return 1;
    }

    // Show the first 16 bytes that follow.
    fputs("after:", stderr);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len && i < 16; i++)
        fprintf(stderr, " %02x", inbuf[i]);
    for (size_t i = len; i < 16 && (ch = getchar()) != EOF; i++)
        fprintf(stderr, " %02x", ch);
    putc('\n', stderr);
    return 0;
}


If the deflated stream is otherwise complete except that the adler32 checksum was removed, would this result in Z_DATA_ERROR when the stream is subsequently inflated?

Yes. But why do you think that?

The file discussed in the OP is a state-save file.  The program loads this file and resumes function at the point of the state-save.  Because of this, it is apparent that the program is able to consume the file and use its content to correctly recreate state.
I'm conjecturing that the entirety of Part 2 is valid compressed data except that the adler32 checksum was removed - but  it's also possible that Part 2 consists of correctly deflated content sufficient for the program to resume function, followed by corrupted data.  I'll need to analyze Part 2 further to be definitive.

Can you provide a link to an example?

Sample is at https://github.com/hankinsohl/Sample.
FWIW successful inflation ends when the following byte sequence is encountered: 02 00 00 00 4E 2E
This is consistent for each data file I've processed so far.

Thanks Mark for the detailed response including source code!
